# How can I upload an .xlsx email attachment to an s3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-s3

I have been attempting to upload a file to an AWS s3 bucket. I keep getting errors no matter how I write that part of the code.
Can someone please point me to where I am going wrong?

Here is the code that I am using:

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
import os.path
import boto3
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']

def get_credentials():
    if os.path.exists('/home/matillion/gmail_token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('/home/matillion/gmail_token.json', SCOPES)
    return creds

service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=get_credentials())

inbox = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', maxResults=2).execute()

for message in inbox['messages']:
    msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
    payload = msg['payload']
    headers = payload['headers']
    parts = payload['parts']

    for d in headers:
        if d['name'] == 'Subject':
            subject = d['value']

    if 'Zillion' and 'payment information' in subject:
        print(subject)

        for attachment in msg['payload']['parts']:
            if attachment['filename'].endswith('.xlsx'):
                # Get the attachment file name
                filename = attachment['filename']
                # Get the attachment body
                attachment_body = attachment['body']

                # Download the attachment to the S3 bucket
                s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
                s3_client.upload_fileobj(attachment_body, 'super-etl-matillion-east', '/client/From_Client/Payment/' + filename)

        # Delete the email
        #service.users().messages().delete(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()

        # Print the filename
        print(filename)
```

I get the following error using this method:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/interpreter-input-c83147df-dde3-4343-b927-48d97c404da8.tmp", line 41, in <module>
    s3_client.upload_fileobj(attachment_body, 'super-etl-matillion-east', '/client/From_Client/Payment/' + filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 618, in upload_fileobj
    raise ValueError('Fileobj must implement read')
ValueError: Fileobj must implement read
```

If I comment out the s3_client.upload_fileobj line, everything runs fine. I get the filename listed. I have attempted to change that line several times and I get other errors. "filename must be a string" and "missing a key" errors.

**UPDATE**
I tried to use the put_object() method and I recieve this error:

```
Fwd: FW: Zillion - payment information
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/interpreter-input-cf44abe6-4df1-495c-bd9e-7ff21ae8a1b4.tmp", line 41, in <module>
    s3_client.put_object(Body=attachment_body,Bucket='super-etl-matillion-east',Key='client/From_Client/Payment/' + filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 391, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 692, in _make_api_call
    api_params, operation_model, context=request_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 740, in _convert_to_request_dict
    api_params, operation_model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/validate.py", line 360, in serialize_to_request
    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Body, value: {'attachmentId': 'ANGjdJ_80Rt2EoNqoLnokG_ygvdEnBzBGtCQIr-5idUxO5iVHQzgxL3fuLejJo3lJKsZYRhAfrjrPDsCX9_fBKeg7q1nT8-Ao1oCyxKWqAyN-6zcdKOo93QvoY-8-L5dAMj_2HBH3ZBxoqB8ei4OaiJKYtIPs3cbbrQ2XyTX2xaWRrP26PmNHDV6abDl5I395yjtKIoJVDbaxag28VMFD5P0UYcQFb-nypmGkQh0OpLbYQkd2Q65qz0sTJSeuBfKDD-ooEEJSWrMF4pWdpsq-N2dKqD5SGX9oAr6Udk6SFUa2BbZRknHb3jfXQdyRA0gRy1FO5vmihqAYULQ23WntO4xvw536oVdyRmj5ouQqvCkWdZC2c9yI_xNpQgHxBfkt3mvinyHeyUQVSrJYnFf', 'size': 33477}, type: <class 'dict'>, valid types: <class 'bytes'>, <class 'bytearray'>, file-like object
Script failed with status: 1
```

Comment: The error means that the first argument to `s3_client.upload_fileobj()` must be a file-like object that has a `.read()` method.  I imagine `attachment_body` is just a plain string instead, or perhaps a byte array.

Comment: John Gordon, I attempted to io to convert the body type and it also fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to create an Amazon S3 object by supplying the contents (as opposed to uploading an existing file from the local disk), you can use [`put_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/put_object.html). It accepts a `Body` parameter of bytes.

Try something like:

```py
s3_client.put_object(Body=attachment_body, Bucket='super-etl-matillion-east', Key='client/From_Client/Payment/' + filename)
```

Also, please note that the Key should **not** start with a `/`.

Comment: I attempted to use the put_object method you suggested above and I received a different error. I updated my main post to show this error.

Comment: The `attachment_body` variable contains JSON: `{'attachmentId': 'ANGjdJ_80Rt2...YnFf', 'size': 33477}`. This does _not_ look like an actual attachment, but rather a reference to a ~32K file. Are you wanting to upload the JSON to S3, or the actual file that it seems to be referencing?

Comment: The actual file

Comment: Well, the `Body` doesn't seem to contain the actual file, so you'll probably need to retrieve it from Matillion somehow.